# How to optimize sql query - tags cloud

Tags: sql, lag, tag-cloud

```
SELECT DISTINCT tag, occurences
FROM ' . DBPREFIX . 'tags
WHERE ID >= 
(
    SELECT 
        FLOOR(MAX(ID) * RAND()) 
    FROM 
        ' . DBPREFIX . 'tags
) AND exclude=0 ORDER BY ID LIMIT ' . MAX_TAGS
```

I have wallpapers site and I have problem with server lags - each time when come visitor to my website are load tags cloud (random 25 tags) and execution this query. I have 4000+ wallpapers and 10000+ tags. How to optimize this query? My site breaking at least 3-5 times per day.

P.S. My friend suggest my to execute the query every 5 min, but I don't know how to realize it.

Comment: Full function:

function get_tags_data ()
{
  $query = $this->db->query
  (
   'SELECT
    DISTINCT tag,
    occurences
   FROM
    ' . DBPREFIX . 'tags
   WHERE ID >= (SELECT FLOOR(MAX(ID) * RAND()) FROM ' . DBPREFIX . 'tags) AND exclude=0 ORDER BY ID LIMIT ' . MAX_TAGS
  );

  return ( $query->num_rows () ) ? $query->result () : FALSE;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Your friend has a good idea. Whatever server-side framework you're using, look for caching options for it.

Another idea would be to get rid of the "random" requirement.

Comment: Just get rid of it. Return whatever the DB gives you as the first 25 records.